# XY plot using android plot

Tags: android

Hello I want to draw graph of y as a function of x and a line between two points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) using android plot.

Help needed for this type of query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have run into a bug that causes the lines to disappear if you have hardware acceleration enabled.

To fix it you need to set android:hardwareAccelerated="false" in the  tag of your AndroidManifest.xml file.

http://androidplot.com/forum/index.php/topic,86.0.html

Comment: Thankfully the upcoming 0.5.2 release finally addresses this issue:

https://androidplot.jira.com/browse/ANDROIDPLOT-129

Answer (score 1):

The [Quickstart](http://androidplot.com/wiki/Quickstart) example will get you going if you are happy calculating the values beforhand.  If you want to be properly dynamic and realy run your function to get the values each time then take a look at the [A dynamic XYPlot](http://androidplot.com/wiki/A_Dynamic_XYPlot) sample.